# No word back on wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I submitted a Wordpress Plugin over a week ago and still haven't gotten back a response, is there any way to figure out what the status is?  It's been really frustrating.

Comment: This isn't a programming question as such, you might find it a better fit over at SO's sister site [Wordpress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or even Wordpress' [official support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/plugins-and-hacks)

Answer (score 1):

A delayed response may suggest you had an incomplete submission - I got mine back within 18 hours.

If you want a rapid response, **make it as easy as possible for the reviewer** to assess whether your plugin is a reasonable attempt at something useful:

- [include a great readme](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/23/improve-wordpress-plugins-readme-txt/), and use the readme test tool to verify it
- [avoid the most common plugin coding mistakes that make everyone's life miserable](http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/09/top-10-most-common-coding-mistakes-in-wordpress-plugins/)
- include a good, short, simple description of the plugin and what it does in the readme and plugin header
- include a link to download the source so they can test it - surprisingly, I suspect this often gets left out!
- ensure you include a link to the site where the plugin is described, instructions given, and a download link provided

If you do all these, you should get a fairly rapid response.  If you do only a few, you'll make the reviewers work harder and they may skip approving yours and focus on other plugins that are easier to assess as they have provided all the above.

Frankly, doing the above things actually makes your plugin more useful to the public, so it's worth spending the extra time - even if your plugin is a sensational idea, if it's not well described nobody will understand how useful it is and it just won't get used!

Comment: Here's [a link to the incredibly useful readme validator ...](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/validator/)